# How can I create a folder in the app folder in the user's AppData folder e.g. C:\User\AppData?

Tags: c#, appdata

I've tried this:

```
var systemPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
var complete = Path.Combine(systemPath, extractfilename);
```

But it results in:

`C:\ProgramData\Extract.txt`

My expected output is:

`C:\User\AppData\Extract.txt`

Comment: Change `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` to `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` - does that give you what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create file in `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` folder.
There is another way also to get its value, so you can use it also and append the path.

e.g.

```
string path;
path = @"%AppData%\test";

Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `C:\User\AppData\Local`

Use [`Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0):

> The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by the **current, non-roaming user**.

---

#### `C:\User\AppData\Roaming`

Use [`Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0):

> The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data for the current roaming user. A roaming user works on more than one computer on a network. **A roaming user's profile is kept on a server on the network** and is loaded onto a system when the user logs on.

Answer (score 1):

This will create a folder named "MyName" in "%appdata%".

```
    string directoryName = "MyName";
    string appDataPath =  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    string mainPath = Path.Combine(appDataPath, directoryName);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(mainPath);
```

This will create a file in "%appdata%" called "MyFile.txt" which says "Hello World".

```
    string text = "Hello Word";
    string fileName = "MyFile.txt";
    string appDataPath =  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    string mainPath = Path.Combine(appDataPath, fileName);
    File.WriteAllText(mainPath, text);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).